# Use inline data and file data in curl POST

Tags: curl, http-post

I'm trying to use curl to do a POST to an app.
I would like to construct the data with inline data and data from a file but I'm not able to do it.

Anyone knows if it's possible?

Here's an example of the code I'm trying:

```
curl -i -X POST http://localhost:3000/admin/articles -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"article": {"issue_id": "1", "title": "hello", "translations_attributes": {"0": {"locale": "en", "id": "", "content": @file.json}}}}'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is more of a workaround but that should do the work in most shells I think.

```
curl -i -X POST http://localhost:3000/admin/articles \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    --data '{"article": {"issue_id": "1", "title": "hello", 
             "translations_attributes": {"0": {"locale": "en", "id": "", 
             "content": '"`cat file.json`"'}}}}'
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I'll leave it open for a couple more days to see if there's a way of using the @ macro from curl to do this. If not, I'll accept your answer as the correct one.